# Different selectors return same object with different prototypes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm really new to JavaScript and jQuery. My question is this.

I have two forms with id `id1` and `id2` in my Doc. The forms have a `validate` method (from jQuery validate module).

When I do:

```
$(#id1).validate()
```

...it works. But when I do:

```
$('form[id^="id"]')[0].validate()
```

...it says `TypeError: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method 'validate'`. This looks strange to me because I'm invoking `validate` on the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're different objects because in the second example you're extracting the DOM element at index `0`...

```
 //  v------returns jQuery object
$('#id1').validate()
```

```
 //     v------returns jQuery object
$('form[id^="id"]')[0].validate()
 //                 ^----------extracts the DOM element
```

The correct equivalent would be...

```
$('form[id^="id"]').validate()
```

...or if you only wanted the first element...

```
$('form[id^="id"]').eq(0).validate()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! A quick follow up question. Is there an easy way to iterate (like map) over the collection of Jquery objects? `map` and `each` both work on the DOM elements.

Comment: @user1279217: Depends on what you want to do. Most jQuery methods iterate implicitly. For example, `$('.myClass').addClass('anotherClass')` will add `'anotherClass'` to all matched elements. If you do use `.each()` or `.map()`, you have the option of taking the current DOM element and passing it to the jQuery function... `$('.myClass').each(function(i, el) { $(el).addClass('anotherClass'); });`